# Reproduzir vídeos privados com a API do Youtube

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, api-youtube

Boa tarde pessoas, estou tentando fazer uma integração com a API do Youtube, onde os vídeos possam ser reproduzidos por um iframe em minha página, que por sinal está em ASP.NET. A documentação me indicou este código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Até aí tudo bem, consegui usá-la corretamente, porém gostaria de saber como faço em caso de vídeos PRIVADOS ? Existe uma maneira de enviar uma autenticação para a API que identifique-me como detentor da conta onde o vídeo foi upado ? Obrigado!

Comment: Eu já usei a API com vídeos privados sem ter que enviar nenhum header e funcionou normalmente. Deu algum erro no console?

Comment: Não, apenas a mensagem no próprio frame de que o vídeo não pode reproduzido porque não está disponível.

Comment: Funciona com vídeo público?

Comment: Sim, com vídeos públicos funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Caro Gabriel, somente com `unlisted` você vai conseguir, private não.

Comment: Ahh é verdade, desta maneira só será possível assistir o vídeo se ele for referenciado diretamente na url. Vai me servir! Obrigado Guilherme ! Posta como resposta que eu marco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `private` creio que é impossível, o que você pode/deve usar é o `unlisted`

Para mudar a privacidade faça os seguintes passos:

1. Inicie sessão na [versão beta do YouTube Studio.](https://studio.youtube.com/)
2. No menu do lado esquerdo, selecione Vídeos.
3. Coloque o cursor do rato sobre o vídeo que pretende atualizar. Selecione o separador
4. Em direto para ver os seus carregamentos em direto.
5. Clique no ícone de lápis em Visibilidade e escolha `Público`, `Privado` ou `Não listado` (no seu caso o último)

Mais detalhes em: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=pt